# After removing an onClick of a button, i'm trying to bring it back but i'm having an interesting issue

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm using

```
   tree = document.getElementById("treeButton");
tree.onclick = function() {
      tree.onclick = null;
}

   treeTwo = document.getElementById("treeButtonTwo");
treeTwo.onclick = function() {
      treeTwo.onclick = null;
}
```

To make sure these buttons (which are actually images with onclicks) can't be clicked. This works just fine and dandy but bringing back the onclick has been tricky!

```
function clickableTree(){
    tree.onclick = cutTree(1);
    treeTwo.onclick = cutTree(2);
}
```

The above code brings back the onclicks to the images, which they do terrifically! But when it does this it also calls the function cutTree(number); which is absolutely not what I want to happen. Before I have this fixed by just saying tree.onclick = cutTree; but now there are two trees and the number needs to be there to allow the function to know which tree to take care of.

Is there any way to not get it to call to the function?

Comment: What is `cutTree()`?  Can you please make a fiddle with the relevant code (HTML, JavaScript).  You can make one and save it [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net).  Make sure to add jquery at the top left if you are using it.

Comment: Did you try putting them in an anonymous function?  function() { cutTree(1); } for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, per my comment above.

```
tree.onclick = function() { cutTree(1); }
treeTwo.onclick = function() { cutTree(2); }
```

I think wrapping them in an anonymous function will prevent the immediate call of the function upon reassignment...?